# How to rewrite empty while block

Tags: java, while-loop, pmd

I have instantiated a `BufferedReader` to read an input stream. It has a boolean `ready()` method that returns false until the reader can be read. Now I have

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(myProcess.getInputStream()));
try {
  while (!br.ready()) {
  }
  String line = br.readLine();
  ...
} catch (IOException e) {
...
```

What PMD warns me about is the empty `while` block and I guess PMD is right. How can I rewrite the code?

Comment: Wouldn't that while loop be infinite? I would think you would want to read the stream in the while loop

Comment: Thank you everybody for the answers. You're all so wonderful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you *don't* want to use `ready()`.  `readLine()` is a blocking call, just call it.

the standard usage of BufferedReader is:

```
String line = null;
while((line = br.readLine) != null) {
  // do stuff with line here ...
}
```

Comment: You mean, if I invoke `readLine()` before it is ready, it will simply wait?

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(myProcess.getInputStream()));
try {
   String line;
   while ( null != (line = br.readLine() )) {
      ...
   }
   ...
 } catch (IOException e) { ... }
```

Comment: Yea ... except that the original version only reads one line.

Comment: @StephenC - Good point, I guessed from the first sentence that this was an attempt to read the *entire* input stream. DrH, can you clarify?

Comment: Consider it confirmed; after `String line = br.readLine();` comes a `while` block with br being read completely.

Answer (score -1):

A way to rewrite it is

```
while(!br.ready());
```

But a more readable way to do this is to read only when the buffer is ready

```
while(br.ready()){
   String line = br.readLine();
   ...
}
```

Comment: It might be more readable, but it also means something different, and it has a real bug in it.  (Whereas the original version is just horribly inefficient!)